# Extending user admin form in django

Tags: django, inheritance, admin, hash

I'm trying to change user admin in Django. In my project the email address, first name and last name is required. I changed my user admin  as following :

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
        self.fields['last_name'].required = True

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserForm
    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_active')

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

The problem is whenever I save a user with a password, it's displayed as without hashing. I guess the problem is, I need to hash the password field with my new form. But the old form does it, so is there a way that I can extend the oldform ?

Answer (score 7):

You can subclass the existing `UserChangeForm` in [`django.contrib.auth.forms`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/forms.py), and customise its behaviour, rather than subclassing `forms.ModelForm`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
        self.fields['last_name'].required = True

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

The above will use the default behaviour for the user password, which is to display the password hash, and link to the password change form. If you want to modify that, I would look at `SetPasswordForm`, to see how the password is set in the Django admin.